# Excluding every nth row in pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I need to exclude every 0th, 3rd, 6th ... row from a table. `\pgfmathparse{Mod(#1, 3) == 0}` did not work inside `row predicate/.code={}`, it gives following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, the operation 'Mod' has not yet been implemented in the floating point unit :-( (in 'Mod(0, 3) == 0').
```

I have copied following MWE from another question. I want to exclude rows according to their indices, not according to their values.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
  num       value
  1         2
  2         5
  1         3
  3         2
  1         4
  2         1
}\data
\pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{num}\of{\data}=1\relax
  \else\pgfplotstableuserowfalse\fi}]{\data}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter every nth row, you can use `\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,3))}` (note the lower case `m`) and then use `\ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax` to check whether to use the row or not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
  num       value
  1         2
  2         5
  1         3
  3         2
  1         4
  2         1
}\data
\pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{num}\of{\data}
  \pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,3))}
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax
  \else\pgfplotstableuserowfalse\fi}]{\data}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to filter by the *value* of a cell, as in your code sample, you'll need to adjust your code slightly:

The `\pgfplotstablegetelem` macro does not expand to its return value; instead, it writes the return value to a macro called `\pgfplotsretval`. If you use that macro in the `\ifnum` condition, it works as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
  num       value
  1         2
  2         5
  1         3
  3         2
  1         4
  2         1
}\data
\pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{num}\of{\data}
  \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=1\relax
  \else\pgfplotstableuserowfalse\fi}]{\data}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very thanks! In my original code, `int(.)` did not work somehow. I have used this code: `row predicate/.code={\pgfmathparse{mod(#1,3)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rem}{\pgfmathresult}\ifnum\rem=0\relax\pgfplotstableuserowfalse\fi},`